# Match words in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I want to match a pattern like this

```
[i]word, anotherword.[/i]
```

and to replace with

```
[[word]], [[anotherword]].
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot work it out with the info there.

Comment: I cannot get a regex that will match exactly the way I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the dot and comma literal,
you can test your [RegEx here](https://regex101.com/r/aALDS4/1) with explanations for every step.

In NotePad++ type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+H ,
enter for search:

```
\[i\]([^,]+), ([^[]+)\.\[\/i\]
```

and for replace:

```
[[$1]], [[$2]].
```

Select the radio button (*) Regular Expression